# Why can't I remove the "disabled" attribute from a textarea using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

It works when I remove the disabled attribute on an input type text field but not textarea, why?

I set the textarea to be disabled like this:

```
    $('#message').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
```

which worked, but then later when I did this:

```
$('#message').removeAttr('disabled');
```

no luck.

The HTML:

```
     <textarea id="message">Type here...</textarea>
```

Comment: does it have a "disabled" attribute to begin with?

Comment: @hunter [Yes](http://jsfiddle.net/Axbrq/)

Comment: no, I meant the OP's textarea, not textareas in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not seeing what you're saying is happening:

```
<textarea id="message" disabled="disabled">Type here...</textarea>

<input type="button" value="Enable Me!" />
```

---

```
$(":button").click(function(){
    $("#message").removeAttr("disabled");
});
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/hunter/TRKzQ/

---

I'm guessing some other javascript error is happening. Is there more code?

Comment: `disabled="disabled"` is a XHTML hassle. Just `<textarea disabled>` is cooler. `:)`

Comment: Sorry about that, you guys were right it was being caused by another issue. Basically I added the disabled attribute via jQuery as a response to a certain user action. I could not use .live() without an event so I ended up solving the issue by replace the entire textarea upon another user action.